# Bootstrap: carousel with parallax without background-img

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, parallax

Iam trying to do parallax effect with bootstrap carousel at the top. I want to cover it by a content.

Here is the code how I have it now without parallax.

```css
.content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/200x80/fff/000" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/200x80/fff/000" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/200x00/fff/000" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="content">
  lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem 
</div>
    
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have already tried so many things. I can not use backgroung-img and then fix it becouse Iam using dynamicly rendering objects. I was thinking about z-index and position relative but that one did not work for me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after long thinking I found out a solution.

Insted of using

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
  <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="${blok.get_obrazek_url(site)}">
</div>
```

I did it like this

```
 <div class="carousel-item active">
   <div class="carousel-image " style="background-image:url('${blok.get_obrazek_url(site)}');"></div>    
 </div>
```

and after this I can use background-attachment in my css file.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qg501xc/13/)

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
      lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem 
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/200x80/8a2908/000" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/200x80/8a2908/000" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/200x80/8a2908/000" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
}

.content{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.content p {
  color: #FF8000;
}

.carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

I made some colour changes to make the text and the carousel indicators more visible.

Comment: thanks for help but that is not actually my problem, I made this one with navbar. But now I want to have content under carousel and when someone scrolls, content goes over the carousel. In the end it should looks like normal parallax https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KBQaZZ